# Callback function with latest angular meteor subscribe call

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

Trying to use `this.subscribe('users')` of latest **meteor**, I would like to know as how to attach function or have callback function along with this

Previously we could have a call back function using then, how can we achieve this in latest angular meteor?

any kind of help or links are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.subscribe('users', () => {
    return [foo, bar]; // publication arguments
}, {
    onReady: (res) => {
        // success callback
    },
    onError: (err) => {
        // error callback
    }
});
```